# What to look for in a first spin bike?

Tags: bicycling

With such a wide variety of brands and functions on the market, what are the main features that should be taken into account when choosing the first spin bike?

For example, a belt or chain transmission?

Comment: Welcome @Mark, I think this is a better fit compared to your last question. I've edited the question and will leave it open for others' opinions.

Comment: For what purpose - home use/general fitness? And do you mean **exercise** bike or specifically a **spin** bike, as they are two distinct things...